# how to get column information from one sheet to another using vlookup

Tags: vlookup

i have a excel sheet with 3 tabs (sales order, customer info, product details). We need to get categories which is listed in product details to sales order sheet using vlookup.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyDMX.png)

Product details has cols product name,product id, category and subcategory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE22x.png)

i have tried using

`vlookup ( =VLOOKUP(J10,Product,3,0) )`

But its not working , its giving an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj5Ld.png)